# How to get rid of `user-select: none` in React Hammer.js?

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

The plugin sets style attribute `user-select: none` to children:

```
<main class="foo" style="touch-action: pan-y; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
   ...
</div>
```

How to get rid of this, how to set `user-select: auto`?

All these do not work.

```
<Hammer onSwipe={this.handleSwipe} options={{defaults: {cssProps: { userSelect: true }} }} >
<Hammer onSwipe={this.handleSwipe} options={{cssProps: { userSelect: true } }} >
<Hammer onSwipe={this.handleSwipe} options={{defaults: { behavior: {cssProps: { userSelect: true }} }}} >
```